# Would ancient accounting records be useful to archaeologists or historians?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-history, ancient-history

I'm creating a story about a team of archaeologists and historians in the present age who discover large library of accounting books from two millennia ago. Those records predates the precursor states that arose in the same territory by 1000 years.

Since the writing system is roughly the same, would those record books be useful?

Comment: For example, the overwhelming majority of [Mycenaean Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycenaean_Greek) texts which have been recovered **are** accounting records...

Comment: Did you know the [oldest known maths mistake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZVs6wF7nC4) was by a ***5000*** year old book keeper? Despite its age, we know not only the man's name, but the name of his supervisor, what he was keeping track of and even *how* he made the mistake! (turns out typos are at least 5000 years old)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have found cuneiform writings from old Mesopotamia which are very often accounts of trades. We have even found the first known example of [customer complaint letter](https://allthatsinteresting.com/first-customer-service-complaint-ea-nasir)!

> “Tell Ea-nasir: Nanni sends the following message:
>
> When you came, you said to me as follows: ‘I will give Gimil-Sin (when he comes) fine quality copper ingots.’ You left then but you did not do what you promised me. You put ingots which were not good before my messenger (Sit-Sin) and said: ‘If you want to take them, take them; if you do not want to take them, go away!’
>
> What do you take me for, that you treat somebody like me with such contempt? I have sent as messengers gentlemen like ourselves to collect the bag with my money (deposited with you) but you have treated me with contempt by sending them back to me empty-handed several times, and that through enemy territory. Is there anyone among the merchants who trade with Telmun who has treated me in this way? You alone treat my messenger with contempt! On account of that one (trifling) mina of silver which I owe you, you feel free to speak in such a way, while I have given to the palace on your behalf 1,080 pounds of copper, and umi-abum has likewise given 1,080 pounds of copper, apart from what we both have had written on a sealed tablet to be kept in the temple of Samas.
>
> How have you treated me for that copper? You have withheld my money bag from me in enemy territory; it is now up to you to restore (my money) to me in full.
>
> Take cognizance that (from now on) I will not accept here any copper from you that is not of fine quality. I shall (from now on) select and take the ingots individually in my own yard, and I shall exercise against you my right of rejection because you have treated me with contempt.”

They are useful because they help understanding some aspects of everyday life, like traded goods, customs and so on.

Comment: they can also give an view of the economy, production abilities, military logistics, time keeping, Taxation, farming practices, even weather and climate. often accounting records are the most helpful things you can find.

Comment: Yeah, that Ea-nasir tried to sell my cousin a bunch of bad-quality copper ingots, too.

Comment: Sounds like a modern Amazon review!  Traders live or die on their reputations.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the records in cuneiform from Hammurabi's time are exactly that -- inventory and bookkeeping (accounting as we know it hadn't been invented yet).  They were invaluable in learning to interpret cuneiform, because the numbers (which were known from other sources) provided context and the repetition gave confidence in translations.

Accounting/bookkeeping/inventory records are some of the most useful, though perhaps less so when dealing with a writing system that's already well known.  But remember, archaeologists are interested in stuff like whether people were cooking their grain, whether it was ground before cooking, whether they ate it as bread or porridge, or only used it to brew beer -- and if they can make a life work out of whether the grain they found was boiled or charred, sprouted or ground from whole kernel, imagine what they can do with intentionally kept records of any kind.

BTW, Hammurabi's rule was nearly two thousand years *older* than what you're asking about.  The time frame of your question is Iron age, early Roman empire days; Hammurabi's rule was centuries before the Bronze Age Collapse.

Answer (score 1):

**Hindu genealogy registers**

What you are looking for is quite similar to the Hindu genealogy registers.
Genealogy registers, of families, maintained by Brahmin Pandits locally called as ‘Pandas’, who double up as professional genealogists, at Haridwar, India.

Basically, these are records of generations of one's family maintained by a group of priests at a specific pilgrimage site in India.

[This guy here](https://www.quora.com/How-far-back-can-one-trace-his-her-ancestry-in-India-What-are-the-options) claimed that he was able to check the records of about 30 generations before him.

[Here is the](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-18442924) detailed first-hand experience of someone from BBC.

It is said that there used to be a Library of Genealogy in Kashi, India destroyed over time due to continuous foreign attacks in Northern India. But whatever remained is still in use and marvelous.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question directly

> Since the writing system is roughly the same, would those record books be useful?

Yes.. of course. Any and all information is always helpful no matter the field. Having extra information and real documents to look back on from millennia ago is a wonderful thing for any historian or even the average person looking to spend some time learning a random fact or two about the past.

A record such as this would give insight on the costs of different objects and show how society in that area and time period treated or valued certain objects. Were they given as gifts? How often were traded? Bartered? Was there a season they were more popular in?

If you do not plan on adding this directly to your world, you can simply gloss over it. Maybe your characters is in a library or antique book store and looks around, finding this as one of the few (or many !) keepsakes, memorials, recollections, histories of the past ...